# Deny access all files with gived extension except for one, how i do?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how i can deny to access to all `php` files EXCEPT for `load.php` located in root directory?
I have:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http:// [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://*$ [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !^/load.php$ [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [F]
```

But don't work. How i can solve?
Thanks.

EDIT:

My full htaccess (for rewriterule):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # Hidden .php extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

  # Hidden WWW from Url
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Deny Access to specific file (Without WWW)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http:// [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://*$ [NC] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loader\.php$ [NC]  
  RewriteRule \.(php)$ - [F]

  # Redirect to https protocol if available
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/load(?:\.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [END]
```

Comment: Hello, i have tried so but don't work yet. Just return Error 500.

Comment: I have added it, in my post (with original code)

Comment: ok my suggested rule is different from what you've shown in question. Which URL have you tried to test it?

Comment: Normal url:  "http://domain/load" (with and without .php)

Comment: There is no reason to keep rules in `# Hidden .php extension` block when you want to block `.php` files except one.

Comment: I have provided full .htaccess in my question. Replace all of your shown code with this one and retest.